# MySQL queries stuck in "sending data" for 30 seconds after migrating to RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, relational-database, query-optimization, innodb

This query (along with a few others I think have a related issue) did not take 30 seconds when MySQL was local on the same EC2 instance as the rest of the website. More like milliseconds.

Does anything look off?

```
SELECT *, chv_images.image_id FROM chv_images
LEFT JOIN chv_storages ON chv_images.image_storage_id = 
chv_storages.storage_id
LEFT JOIN chv_users ON chv_images.image_user_id = chv_users.user_id
LEFT JOIN chv_albums ON chv_images.image_album_id = chv_albums.album_id
LEFT JOIN chv_categories ON chv_images.image_category_id = 
chv_categories.category_id
LEFT JOIN chv_meta ON chv_images.image_id = chv_meta.image_id
LEFT JOIN chv_likes ON chv_likes.like_content_type = "image" AND 
chv_likes.like_content_id = chv_images.image_id AND chv_likes.like_user_id = 1
LEFT JOIN chv_follows ON chv_follows.follow_followed_user_id = 
chv_images.image_user_id
LEFT JOIN chv_follows_projects ON 
chv_follows_projects.follows_project_project_id = 
chv_images.image_project_id LEFT JOIN chv_projects ON 
chv_projects.project_id = follows_project_project_id WHERE 
chv_follows.follow_user_id='1' OR (follows_project_user_id = 1 AND 
chv_projects.project_privacy = "public" AND 
chv_projects.project_is_public_upload = 1)  GROUP BY chv_images.image_id 
ORDER BY chv_images.image_id DESC
LIMIT 0,15
```

[And this is what EXPLAIN shows:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHGkk.png)

Thank you

Update: This query has the same issue. It does not have a GROUP BY.

```
 SELECT *, chv_images.image_id FROM chv_images
 LEFT JOIN chv_storages ON chv_images.image_storage_id = 
 chv_storages.storage_id
 LEFT JOIN chv_users ON chv_images.image_user_id = chv_users.user_id
 LEFT JOIN chv_albums ON chv_images.image_album_id = chv_albums.album_id
 LEFT JOIN chv_categories ON chv_images.image_category_id = 
 chv_categories.category_id
 LEFT JOIN chv_meta ON chv_images.image_id = chv_meta.image_id
 LEFT JOIN chv_likes ON chv_likes.like_content_type = "image" AND 
 chv_likes.like_content_id = chv_images.image_id AND chv_likes.like_user_id = 1

 ORDER BY chv_images.image_id DESC
 LIMIT 0,15
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might not be aware that it's best to include the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for all tables in your query, when you ask a query-optimization question. That will help folks who answer your question to know what data types, indexes, constraints you have used. Help us help you!

Comment: Hi Bill, SHOW CREATE TABLE query gives an error. #1064.

Comment: Did you give the name of the table as an argument? See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-create-table.html

Comment: When supplying the name of the table, it doesn't give an error but it also doesn't provide a result in phpmyadmin.

Comment: Which table is `follows_project_user_id` in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That EXPLAIN shows several table-scans (`type: ALL`), so it's not surprising that it takes over 30 seconds.

Here's your EXPLAIN:
[image]

Notice the column `rows` shows an estimated 14420 rows read from the first table chv_images. It's doing a table-scan of all the rows.

In general, when you do a series of JOINs, you can multiple together all the values in the `rows` column of the EXPLAIN, and the final result is how many row-reads MySQL has to do. In this case it's 14420 * 2 * 1 * 1 * 2 * 1 * 916, or **52,834,880** row-reads. That should put into perspective the high cost of doing several table-scans in the same query.

You might help avoid those table-scans by creating some indexes on these tables:

```
ALTER TABLE chv_storages
  ADD INDEX (storage_id);

ALTER TABLE chv_categories
  ADD INDEX (category_id);

ALTER TABLE chv_likes
  ADD INDEX (like_content_id, like_content_type, like_user_id);
```

Try creating those indexes and then run the EXPLAIN again.

The other tables are already doing lookups by primary key (`type: eq_ref`) or by secondary key (`type: ref`) so those are already optimized.

Your EXPLAIN shows your query uses a temporary table and filesort. You should reconsider whether you need the GROUP BY, because that's probably causing the extra work.

Another tip is to avoid using `SELECT *` because it might be forcing the query to read many extra columns that you don't need. Instead, explicitly name only the columns you need.

Comment: I ran the above query and nothing happened. No green or red.

Comment: I have the same issue with the following similar query:

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about when you say green or red. I don't use a GUI tool for MySQL. Are you saying the `ADD INDEX` did not execute?

Comment: I'm using phpymyadmin so I am referring to a query processing or error-ing. Your query suggestion did not say it did anything, and running it again doesn't give an error saying it has already added an index.

Comment: To be clear, there are no keys in the EXPLAIN after running your query. Should there be?

Comment: I don't know if alter table is working as expected. No changes to the EXPLAIN after running the query many times. Great explanation though.

Comment: You must not have executed the ALTER TABLE. Well, good luck! If you ever figure out how to do that, I predict the indexes will help.

Comment: Kindly may I ask how the key references are set? Or is that automatic?

Comment: I also just got the query to execute! Still no changes to EXPLAIN though. :(

Comment: Oh wait, I guess something did change because the website WORKS! WOOOHOOO

Comment: Indexes are created by the ALTER TABLE statements I showed. MySQL takes care of choosing the right indexes as it analyzes each query before you run it. It will know that the new indexes exist, and it will use them automatically if its analysis shows they will help.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any indexes in chv_images?

I propose:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_image_id ON chv_images (image_id);
```

Comment: I ran this query and no noticeable changes to the EXPLAIN.

Answer (score 0):

(Bill's ideas are good.  I'll take the discussion a different way...)

**Explode-Implode --**  If the `LEFT JOINs` match no more than 1 row, change, for example,

```
SELECT 
    ...
    LEFT JOIN  chv_meta  ON chv_images.image_id = chv_meta.image_id
```

into

```
SELECT ...,
    ( SELECT foo FROM chv_meta WHERE image_id = chv_images.image_id ) AS foo, ...
```

If that can be done for *all* the `JOINs`, you can get rid of `GROUP BY`.  This will avoid the costly "explode-implode" where `JOINs` lead to more rows, then `GROUP BY` gets rid of the dups.  (I suspect you can't move all the joins in.)

**OR -> UNION --**  `OR` is hard to optimize.  Your query looks like a good candidate for turning into `UNION`, then making more indexes that will become useful.

```
    WHERE  chv_follows.follow_user_id='1'
      OR  (follows_project_user_id = 1
              AND  chv_projects.project_privacy = "public"
              AND  chv_projects.project_is_public_upload = 1
          )
```

Assuming that `follows_project_user_id` is in `chv_images,

```
( SELECT ...
    WHERE chv_follows.follow_user_id='1' )
UNION DISTINCT   -- or ALL, if you are sure there won't be dups
( SELECT ...
    WHERE follows_project_user_id = 1
      AND  chv_projects.project_privacy = "public"
      AND  chv_projects.project_is_public_upload = 1 )
```

Indexes needed:

```
chv_follows:  (follow_user_id)
chv_projects: (project_privacy, project_is_public_upload) -- either order
```

But this has not yet handled the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`.  The general pattern for such:

```
( SELECT ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT 15 )
UNION
( SELECT ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT 15 )
ORDER BY ... LIMIT 15
```

Yes, the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` are repeated.

That works for page 1.  If you want the next 15 rows, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination#pagination_and_union

After building those two sub-selects, look at them; I think you will be able to optimize each one, and may need new indexes because the Optimizer will start with a different 'first' table.